# Make a event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div which is `cloned` on clicking image next to And.

Right click event listeners are working in jsfiddle but not actually working in my page. :(

Do i need to do something extra. I tried adding different jquery links , but to no avail.

Comment: If it's working in the fiddle but not your page, check you've got closure over your variables and aren't accidentally causing a variable name conflict in your global namespace

Comment: Trying to figure out what is wrong in my page. And could you helpme out with the 2nd problem. When i clone a div, then right click on div and select some other option from context menu all div gets updated. I want only thar particular to get updated. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your issue but when cloning the div you end up with multiple elements with the same id (invalid HTML).

Comment: But i am using class to replace text and not ID

Comment: Well there lies your problem, you are selecting all the elements with that class.  You will need to find a way to select only the one you are interested in.

Comment: You should open another question as it is a different issue.

Comment: I guess i have written it in same question at start only

Comment: I don't even understand what your first sentence means.

Comment: We need code if we're going to have any chance of actually fixing the problem.